# C pipe to write / read sequence of doubles fails

Tags: c, pipe, ipc

For this C project I am trying to use a pipe to get a parent process to communicate with a child. The child is supposed to read lines (one each second) from a txt file (containing real numbers) and use a pipe to supply the parent, which in turn should read from the pipe and write the numbers into a log file. However the parent process only reads a sequence of 0.000000. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <wait.h>
#define MAX_I 5
#define delay 1
void read_input(FILE *fp);

FILE *file_log;
int status;
pid_t pid;
int pipeFD[2];

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
//initialize
    FILE *fp;

    if (argc != 2){
    if ((fp = fopen("input.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error! opening file");
        exit(1);}
    }
    else{
        fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        }

    if (pipe(pipeFD) == -1){    /* creates a pipe */
    fprintf(stderr, "\nERROR: pipe() failed\n");
    exit(1);}

    file_log=fopen("file.log","w+"); /*open the log file*/

    pid=fork();
    if(pid==0) {//child process
    printf ("%d starts \n", getpid());
    close(pipeFD[0]);//close read end for child
    read_input(fp);
    return 0;
    exit(status);
    }else{//parent 
    double speed_read;
    close(pipeFD[1]);//close write end for parent
    while(1){
        if (read(pipeFD[0], &speed_read, sizeof(speed_read)) >0){
        if (speed_read<0)
        break;
        fprintf(file_log, "%f \n", speed_read); 
        printf("process %d received %f from child \n",getpid(),speed_read);
        }else
            printf("Nothing there to read \n");  
        }
    printf("parent ended \n");
    wait(&status);
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(file_log);
    }
    return 0;
}

void read_input(FILE *fp){
    char *line = NULL;
    double speed;
    int i=0; size_t len = 0; double exit_sign =-10.0;
    while(getline(&line, &len, fp) != -1) { 
        speed=atof(line);
        i++;
        if(i>MAX_I){//reads up to MAX_I rows of input
                        printf("I'll send the exit sign to parent now\n");
                        write(pipeFD[1], &exit_sign, sizeof(double));
                        free(line);
                        break;      
                    }
        if(write(pipeFD[1], &speed, sizeof(double)>0)){
            printf("%d at %d wrote that speed is %f\n",getpid(), i,speed);
        }else{printf("Write on pipe failed\n");}
        sleep(delay);
        }
    free(line);
}
```

Here is what is printed:

---

15032 starts

15032 at 1 wrote that speed is 0.345670

process 15031 received 0.000000 from child

15032 at 2 wrote that speed is 12.678890

process 15031 received 0.000000 from child

15032 at 3 wrote that speed is 34.789870

process 15031 received 0.000000 from child

15032 at 4 wrote that speed is 0.000000

process 15031 received 0.000000 from child

15032 at 5 wrote that speed is 12.009288

process 15031 received 0.000000 from child

I'll send the exit sign to parent now

parent ended

---

Likewise the log file consists in the following:

0.000000

0.000000

0.000000

0.000000

0.000000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in *read_input* the line :

> ```
> if(write(pipeFD[1], &speed, sizeof(double)>0)){
> ```

must be

```
if(write(pipeFD[1], &speed, sizeof(double))>0){
```

in your case you do not write `sizeof(double)` bytes but only 1

Note *read_input* does two times `free(line);` with an undefined behavior, you must remove the one when `if(i>MAX_I){`

After the corrections, compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -Wall p.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat input.txt 
1.2
2.3
3.45
7.8
9.12
12.345
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
15121 starts 
15121 at 1 wrote that speed is 1.200000
process 15120 received 1.200000 from child 
15121 at 2 wrote that speed is 2.300000
process 15120 received 2.300000 from child 
15121 at 3 wrote that speed is 3.450000
process 15120 received 3.450000 from child 
15121 at 4 wrote that speed is 7.800000
process 15120 received 7.800000 from child 
15121 at 5 wrote that speed is 9.120000
process 15120 received 9.120000 from child 
I'll send the exit sign to parent now
parent ended 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat file.log
1.200000 
2.300000 
3.450000 
7.800000 
9.120000 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

---

Out of that when you detect the EOF and do `printf("Nothing there to read \n");` to also do a `break;` to finish the `while` seems better. Note you can also send *exit_sign* when you reach the end of the input file in *read_input*. If you don't the parent never ends writing *Nothing there to read* if the input file has less than *MAX_I* lines

---

A *pipe* is a *stream* but [reading or writing pipe data is atomic if the size of data written is not greater than PIPE_BUF](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pipe-Atomicity.html) where [PIPE_BUF is at least 512 bytes, and 4096 under Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)

So in your case where in *main* you read as fast as possible and the *read_input* function sleeps, while you read and write the same small amount of bytes, you have no risk. Else as in general when you read in a stream you need to loop until you get the expected amount of bytes, for instance replacing the use of `read` by a call to a function like :

```
int read_block(int f, char * p, size_t sz)
{
  ssize_t n;

  while ((n = read(f, p, sz)) > 0) {
    if ((sz -= (size_t) n) == 0)
      return 1;
    p += n;
  }

  return -1;
}
```

Comment: Also, the code should be prepared for the possibility of a partial read/write, that processes at least 1 byte but not the full `sizeof(double)`.

Comment: @NateEldredge yes, a pipe is a stream. I didn't not because I was afraid this is too complicated for the OP, but finally you help to me change my mind and  I will edit my answer

Comment: @Bruno. That is really helpful. My code is indeed quite buggy. I'll take advantage of your other comments to improve it.

Comment: Writes to a pipe that are less than the pipe buffer size are atomic, and `sizeof(double)` is much smaller than the pipe buffer size.  If you read `sizeof(double)` bytes and only write `sizeof(double)` bytes at any time, there won't be partial reads and writes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler oh yes you are right : https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pipe-Atomicity.html

Comment: @NateEldredge we was wrong : https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pipe-Atomicity.html